# Tkinter does not show one frame

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI for my program but I have changed my code a lot and I saw that GUI misses one frame but it was fine before.
Could anyone help me and tell why a frame with a button does not appear on the bottom?

Whole "button_part" object does not appear.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import os
import glob

BOUNDS = ["Last week", "Last 2 weeks", "Last 3 weeks"]


class settings_part:
    path_to_copy = 0

    def __init__(self, master, update_func):
        path_to_copy = StringVar()
        settings_frame = Frame(master, background="")
        settings_frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
        date_bound = StringVar()
        date_bound.set(BOUNDS[1])
        date_option = OptionMenu(settings_frame, date_bound, *BOUNDS, command=update_func)
        date_option.config(background="#732c30")
        date_option.config(foreground="white")
        date_option.config(bd=0)
        date_option.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        path_to_copy.set("~/Python/usun")
        box_with_path = Entry(settings_frame, textvariable=path_to_copy)
        box_with_path.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)
        # s = path_to_copy.get()


class songs_part:
    def __init__(self, master, root):
        self.songs_frame = Frame(master)
        self.update_songs(root.list_of_songs)
        self.songs_frame.pack()

    def update_songs(self, l):
        for song in l:
            c = Checkbutton(self.songs_frame, text=song[0], variable=song[1])
            c.pack()


class button_part:
    def __init__(self, master, copyFunc):
        self.button_frame = Frame(master)
        btn_image = PhotoImage(file="copybtn.png")
        self.copy_button = Button(self.button_frame, command=copyFunc, text="Copy",
                                  image=btn_image, highlightthickness=0, bd=0, activebackground="#732c30")
        self.copy_button.pack()


class App:

    def __init__(self):
        root = Tk()

        root.title("Copying songs")
        root.geometry("500x500")
        root.option_add("*Font", "Calibra")
        back_image = PhotoImage(file="back.png")

        self.window = Label(root, image=back_image)
        self.window.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")

        self.list_of_songs = list()

        self.make_list_of_songs()

        self.set_part = settings_part(self.window, self.update_list)
        self.son_part = songs_part(self.window, self)
        self.but_part = button_part(self.window, self.copy_songs)

        root.mainloop()

    def make_list_of_songs(self):
        owd = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir("/home/stanek/Music/usun")
        for file in glob.glob("*.mp3"):
            self.list_of_songs.append([file, tk.IntVar()])
        os.chdir(owd)

    def copy_songs(self):
        for s in self.list_of_songs:
            print(s)

    def update_list(self, arg):
        print("updating list with songs from " + arg)
        self.son_part = songs_part(self.window, self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never pack the button frame.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Anyway it does not show image but grey rectangle :/ It used to work before and the image is okey :/

Comment: ok, thanks. I have changed "btnimage" to "self.btnimage" and it works, is this solution a proper one?